# How to continue scanning BLE device

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making an Android app to receive data from Arduino(NRF24L01).

Arduino(NRF24L01) can send data only with Bluetooth device name.

So I get the value by putting the analog value in the BLEname.

Like this YouTube video.

https://youtu.be/F9yMTdcd33w?t=240

However, the Android application does not come back with the information of a device once it is already connected.

ex)

- BLE Device name : "A=i" //(i=analog.value;)
- first BLE SCAN -> find -> BLE Device name : "A=12"
- I change i,(i=14;)
- Second BLE SCAN -> find -> BLE Device name : "A=12"
- why????????? i want "A=14"!!

Therefore, I would like to create an application that will continue to scan and retrieve device name information.

Is there any example I can refer to?

P.S I am sorry that I have not translated the translator and the context is not smooth.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this example for BLE scanning and connection or you can use customize as you want.
[**BleConnect**](https://github.com/tjdam007/BleConnect)

Comment: thanks!!
i wanted refresh ble cache!!
i found out 'refresh' method , thank you!